# xml data to dynamic text AS3 flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, rss, feed

Can't figure it out. Basically I have this code fetching data from: http://www.cbbh.ba/kursna_bs.xml
I can't move the data to a single line and `<br />` is showing. My code is:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.cbbh.ba/kursna_bs.xml"));

/* This loads the XML */
function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
parseData(xmlData);
 }

 /* This gets the data for today's tip */
 function parseData(mTip:XML):void {

     var itemXMLList:XMLList = XMLList(mTip..item);
     var count:int = itemXMLList.length();
     var finalcount:int = count - 1;
     //trace(finalcount);



 flashTip.htmlText = XMLList(mTip..item);

 }
```

Comment: Do you want only remove `<br />` tags from the output?

Comment: yes and if could be possible to generate data inside dynamic text in flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
flashTip.htmlText = XMLList(mTip..item).toString().replace(/&lt;br \/&gt;\s*/g,"\t");
```

Output:

> Šifra valute: 978
>    EMU (EUR)
>    Jedinica: 1    Kupovni za devize: 1.95583    Srednji za devize: 1.95583    Prodajni za devize: 1.95583
>
> Šifra valute: 36
>    Australija (AUD)
>    Jedinica: 1    Kupovni za devize: 1.286221    Srednji za devize: 1.289445    Prodajni za devize: 1.292669